Baseline3 TD3, reset() method too many values to unpack error
The env is python 3.10, stable-baseline3 2.3.0 and I'm trying TD3 Algorithm.
I'm keep getting same error for whatever I do.
As far as I know, the reset method has return as same as observation space defined
The environment I made has reset method like below
def reset(self, seed=0):
    self.current_index = 0
    self.current_cash = self.start_cash
    self.done = False
    self.current_time = self.start_time

    # 초기 관찰 상태 계산
    initial_state = self.get_state()  # dict
    return initial_state

Its never been complicated whatsoever and define env, model is also fine
from stable_baselines3.common.torch_layers import BaseFeaturesExtractor
from stable_baselines3 import TD3

class CustomFeatureExtractor(BaseFeaturesExtractor):
    def __init__(self, observation_space, features_dim=5):
        super(CustomFeatureExtractor, self).__init__(observation_space, features_dim)
        self.model_alpha = ModelAlpha()
    
    def forward(self, observations):
        prices = observations['prices']
        position = observations['position']
        quantity = observations['quantity']
        pnr = observations['pnr']
        
        return self.model_alpha(prices, torch.cat([position, quantity, pnr]))
        
        
# 환경과 모델 설정
env = MarketEnvironment(candles, '2020-07-01 00:00:00', '2023-12-31 23:59:00') # 여러분의 환경 설정
policy_kwargs = dict(
    features_extractor_class=CustomFeatureExtractor,
    features_extractor_kwargs=dict(features_dim=5)
)

model = TD3("MultiInputPolicy", env, policy_kwargs=policy_kwargs, batch_size=128, verbose=1)

Jupyter prompt says that
Using cpu device
Wrapping the env with a Monitor wrapper
Wrapping the env in a DummyVecEnv.
and it runs fine until
model.learn(total_timesteps=1, log_interval=10, progress_bar=True)

this code.
It keep saying that again and again no matter what I've done
File ~\.conda\envs\mlbase-py3.10\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\off_policy_algorithm.py:297, in OffPolicyAlgorithm._setup_learn(self, total_timesteps, callback, reset_num_timesteps, tb_log_name, progress_bar)
    290 if (
    291     self.action_noise is not None
    292     and self.env.num_envs > 1
    293     and not isinstance(self.action_noise, VectorizedActionNoise)
    294 ):
    295     self.action_noise = VectorizedActionNoise(self.action_noise, self.env.num_envs)
--> 297 return super()._setup_learn(
    298     total_timesteps,
    299     callback,
    300     reset_num_timesteps,
    301     tb_log_name,
    302     progress_bar,
    303 )

File ~\.conda\envs\mlbase-py3.10\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\base_class.py:425, in BaseAlgorithm._setup_learn(self, total_timesteps, callback, reset_num_timesteps, tb_log_name, progress_bar)
    423 if reset_num_timesteps or self._last_obs is None:
    424     assert self.env is not None
--> 425     self._last_obs = self.env.reset()  # type: ignore[assignment]
    426     self._last_episode_starts = np.ones((self.env.num_envs,), dtype=bool)
    427     # Retrieve unnormalized observation for saving into the buffer

File ~\.conda\envs\mlbase-py3.10\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\vec_env\dummy_vec_env.py:77, in DummyVecEnv.reset(self)
     75 for env_idx in range(self.num_envs):
     76     maybe_options = {"options": self._options[env_idx]} if self._options[env_idx] else {}
---> 77     obs, self.reset_infos[env_idx] = self.envs[env_idx].reset(seed=self._seeds[env_idx], **maybe_options)
     78     self._save_obs(env_idx, obs)
     79 # Seeds and options are only used once

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

What I know is that the reset() method of this error is in an abstract class named VecEnv
How to resolve this?

Solve this issue. Its because gymnasium update step, reset function spec about return value. env.reset() returns initial state *and additional info dictionary. I don't know why at this stage, but there must be some reason. env.step() has same issue that it returns terminated: bool value *and truncated:bool which indicate the episode is stopped with other reason like time over, failure or something.
After all this, I simply encounter dead kernel issue with no traceable message lol
